# React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop with too many re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My Main Motto is to use the Dark mode feature. In this case i'm Taking a Prop from app.js and assigning it to a state pMode and i am trying to change the class of the navbar using the setPmode method which is used as Ternary in onclick of Input tag and i am getting error of

> Error : Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

export default function Navbar(props) {
    let [pMode,setPmode] = useState(props.Mode);
    return (
        <>
            <nav className={`navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-${pMode} bg-${pMode}`}>
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">Navbar</a>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNav">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="/">Features</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="/">Pricing</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div className="form-check form-switch">
                            <input className="form-check-input" onClick={pMode=== "light"? setPmode("dark") : setPmode("light")} type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" />
                            <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexSwitchCheckDefault">{pMode} mode</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This arrow function help with Infinite re-rendering.

onClick={()=>pMode=== "light"? setPmode("dark") : setPmode("light")}

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

export default function Navbar(props) {
    let [pMode,setPmode] = useState(props.Mode);
    return (
        <>
            <nav className={`navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-${pMode} bg-${pMode}`}>
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">Navbar</a>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNav">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="/">Features</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="/">Pricing</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div className="form-check form-switch">
                            <input className="form-check-input" onClick={()=>pMode=== "light"? setPmode("dark") : setPmode("light")} type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" />
                            <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexSwitchCheckDefault">{pMode} mode</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: thx bro working i will tick as answer in 2 mins

Answer (score 1):

You need to slightly modify the `onClick` function

```js
<input
 className="form-check-input"
 onClick={() => setPMode((prev) => prev === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light')}
 type="checkbox"
 role="switch"
 id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" />
```

The issue earlier was that your onClick was a function call instead of a function. So every time the component rendered, the function call was executed which caused a change in state and then a re render. Also when your new state depends on previous state, it is recommended to use a function to setState

Answer (score 1):

```
onClick={()=>{pMode=== "light"? setPmode("dark") : setPmode("light")}}
```

If you want to execute code inside onclick, you should use the arrow function.